# NodeJS, Angular Seed, Gulp, Jasmine , Karma issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gulp, karma-jasmine

Setting up a Angular Seed and I have everything working , I could even launch the jasmine browser but for some reason my spec's were not working so I added a karma.conf file and it seems to have broken the jasmine browser. I am new to using Jasmine so I am at a loss there are a lot of opinions as to how best to do it, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it to work, I have added the repo link here for the code . Hopefully someone might be able to see what I am doing wrong.

This Seed Requires NodeJS

Download the git, put it in a folder 
go to the folder and enter the config folder in the root
run npm install
then run gulp, it will automatically launch in a browser 
in the console you will see this error

```
[14:52:17] 'jasmineWeb' errored after 2.27 ms
[14:52:17] TypeError: object is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/webdev/E20/config/gulpfile.js:137:11)
     at module.exports (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at /webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
at finish (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
at module.exports (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:60:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
at /webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:279:18
```

Here is the task I use to launch Jasmine

```
gulp.task('jasmineWeb', function() {
   var filesForTest = ['../src/**/*.js', '../src/**/*_spec.js'] 
  return gulp.src(filesForTest)
     .pipe(karma({configFile: 'karma.conf.js',action: 'run'}))
     .pipe(watch(filesForTest))
     .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner())
     .pipe(jasmineBrowser.server({port: 8888}));
});
```

Here is my Karma.conf file

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jul 28 2015 11:28:22 GMT-0400 (EDT)

 module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

     // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files,    exclude)
    basePath: '',


     // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     frameworks: ['jasmine'],


     // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
     files: [
       '../src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js',
       '../src/lib/js/angular/angular-mocks.js',
       '../src/com/**/*.js',
       '../src/com/**/*_spec.js'
     ],

     // list of files to exclude
     exclude: [
     ],


     // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
     // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
     preprocessors: {
     },


     // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
     // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
     reporters: ['progress'],


     // web server port
     port: 9876,


     // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


     // level of logging
     // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR ||   config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
     logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


     // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
      autoWatch: true,


     // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'IE', 'PhantomJS'],


     // Continuous Integration mode
     // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
     singleRun: false
  })
}
```

I appreciate it in advance

https://bitbucket.org/baylysoft/angular-seed-project

Karma is now running but I am getting this error now

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: com/modules/AboutController Sets the Page Message It should show the page message FAILED
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $scope
        at /webdev/E20/src/com/modules/about/aboutController_spec.js:15
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Mac OS X 10.10.4) Controller: com/modules/AboutController Sets the Page Message It should show the page message FAILED
    ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/webdev/E20/src/com/modules/about/aboutController_spec.js:15:16)
Chrome 44.0.2403 (Mac OS X 10.10.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.008 secs / 0.006 secs)
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0 secs / 0.004 secs)
```

Here is the updated spec file

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: com/modules/AboutController', function() {
  beforeEach(module(app));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('Sets the Page Message', function() {
    it('It should show the page message', function() {
        expect($scope.message).toEqual('This is the about page message from the controller');
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Here is the link to the repository for the project in case more information is needed                                                         https://bitbucket.org/baylysoft/angular-seed-project

Answer (score 2):

After going back and forth and getting help from a few people on here (Thank you all very much btw) I was able to find the culprit, turns out the issue wasn't in the actual test but in the karma configuration file, it was deceptive the issue was the bower components I was loading, I wasn't loading enough ng-mocks wasn't enough to test to  controllers, so I added a few others and it worked, I was able to get all my tests to work properly.

here is what I added under the karma.conf files section

```
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        '../src/com/**/*.js',
        '../src/com/**/*_spec.js'
```

I have updated the bitbucket seed with the new working code for those who want a better example

bitbucket.org/baylysoft/angular-seed-project

Answer (score 1):

I run Jasmine, Karma, and use Gulp just as you do. However there are some differences in how I start it up. Perhaps this may help with yours.

Your karma.config.js looks similar, so probably no problems there.

However, in my gulp file I just call this

```
gulp.task( 'karma', function( done ){
  karma.start({
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done );
});

gulp karma
```

If you need to watch files for changes as well, then you can run this instead.

```
var filesForTest = [ '../src/**/*.js' ];

gulp.task( 'watchOnSave', function(){
  gulp.watch( filesForTest, [ 'karma' ]);
}

gulp watchOnSave
```

The karma.config.js file will execute the browser for you, as well as run your specs that you defined in your karma.config.js file.

```
  '../src/com/**/*_spec.js' // just make sure all your JS files are in your karma **files** property.
```

Let me know if this works, or we'll TS to the solution.

**UPDATE**

In your app (app.js), you have this

```
var appName = 'EuropaSeed';

var globalApp = angular.module(appName,['ngRoute','ngCookies']);
var app = angular.module(appName);
```

and in your testing you have

```
beforeEach(module('EuroSeed'));
```

One of your issues, is that you have two modules named EuroSeed

```
app and globalApp
```

So instead in your test, call out which of the two modules you require as in

```
beforeEach(module(app));
```

which matches what you have in your controller

```
app.controller('AboutController',...
```

I am using this to run the spec, which is passing now but without using the except as there is another issue to getting that to pass.

gulp file as

```
gulp.task('karma', function (done) {
  karma.server.start({ // had to add .server to karma
    configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js'
  }, done);
});
```

[image: success]

---

it might be the spec, so I figured I would post the spec and controller here, they are very simple.

Now "app" is set in the app.js file so the application itself works

aboutcontroller

```
//This is the about function that is used in the About Module. 
    'use strict';
     app.controller('AboutController',// jshint ignore:line
        ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
           $scope.message = 'This is the about page message from the controller';
        }]);
```

aboutcontroller test

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: com/modules/AboutController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('EuropaSeed'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter     names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('Sets the Page Message', function() {
    it('It should show the page message', function() {
        expect($scope.message).toEqual('This is the about page message from the controller');
    });

  });
});
```

I pulled the test I was running and I am still getting the same error on jasmineWeb so it might possibly be the configuration.

```
Europas-MacBook-Pro:config ray$ gulp jasmineWeb
[08:29:33] Using gulpfile /webdev/E20/config/gulpfile.js
[08:29:33] Starting 'jasmineWeb'...
[08:29:33] 'jasmineWeb' errored after 12 ms
[08:29:33] TypeError: object is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/webdev/E20/config/gulpfile.js:137:11)
    at module.exports (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
Europas-MacBook-Pro:config ray$
```

I took your suggestion and added the karma task to the gulp file , its giving me the same results so , I definitely screwed up the configuration somewhere .

```
Europas-MacBook-Pro:config ray$ gulp karma
[08:31:46] Using gulpfile /webdev/E20/config/gulpfile.js
[08:31:46] Starting 'karma'...
[08:31:46] 'karma' errored after 145 μs
[08:31:46] TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/webdev/E20/config/gulpfile.js:144:9)
    at module.exports (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/webdev/E20/config/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Here is the updated spec I am running

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: com/modules/AboutController', function() {

    beforeEach(module(app));

    var AboutController,
        scope;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            AboutController = $controller('AboutController', {
                "$scope": scope
            });
        }));
    it('It should show the page message', function () {
        // you might also need to do this
        AboutController();
        expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("This is the about page message from the controller");
                                       });

    });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84741/discussion-on-answer-by-soezpz-nodejs-angular-seed-gulp-jasmine-karma-issue).